# Como utilizar o conteúdo de uma variável javascript em outro arquivo js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variáveis

Estou criando minha primeira aplicação com nodejs e tenho uma dúvida no javascript. No código abaixo estou fazendo a leitura de um sensor e salvando na variável **valor** a cada 30 segundos, gostaria de saber se posso utilizar essa variável e seu valor em outro arquivo js? Como seria feito isso?

```
var five = require("johnny-five"),
  board, potentiometer;

board = new five.Board();


board.on("ready", function() {

  potentiometer = new five.Sensor({
    pin: "A2",
    freq: 30000
  });

  board.repl.inject({
    pot: potentiometer
  });

  potentiometer.on("data", function() {
      var valor = this.value;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Tens de criar uma maneira de comunicar entre ficheiros. O `require` é pedido uma vez por módulo e fica em memória. Se passares uma função então tens a porta aberta para ir buscando, ou empurrando novos valores.

Poderia ser algo assim:

#### Ficheiro A:

```
var five = require("johnny-five");
var sensor = require('./sensor'); // um ficheiro sensor.js na mesma diretoria

var board, potentiometer;
board = new five.Board();


board.on("ready", function() {

  potentiometer = new five.Sensor({
    pin: "A2",
    freq: 30000
  });

  board.repl.inject({
    pot: potentiometer
  });

  potentiometer.on("data", function() {
      var valor = this.value;
      var sensorValue = sensor(); // <--- aqui vais buscar o valor de "sensor"

  });
});
```

#### Ficheiro B (sensor.js)

```
var valor = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    valor = Math.random() * 100; // valor muda a cada 0.5 segundos
}, 500);

module.exports = function(){
    return valor;
}
```

Comment: Sergio valeu pela ajuda, porém nesse caso eu teria que passar a variável valor do ficheiro A para o B. Se fizer um return da variável valor no ficheiro A e um require no ficheiro B, irá funcionar?

Comment: @GiovaneZanon podes explicar qual a variável é, se é A que quer informar B pu se é B que precisa de ir buscar a A?